# How do you prevent Modal dialog from closing when users clicks outside of the modal dialog box In JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm stuck on a old project using `Jquery UI` to display `Modals` on view. The issue that I am having is that the dialog modal view is  closing when user clicks outside of `Model Dialog`. In `Jquery` is there a property to prevent this? I know that backdrop and keyboard property in `Bootstrap` would help in `Boostrap` in preventing closing of modal base on outside click but what is the case with `Jquery UI`?

Here's my `Javascript` code below:

```
// EDit Dialog
var updateBanquetTicketDialog = function () {
    var s = $('<div></div>').dialog({
        title: "Edit Banquet Ticket",
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: "success-dialog",
        modal: true,

        buttons: [
           {
               text: "Update"
             , 'class': "btn-primary"
             , click: function () {
                 updateBanquetTicket();
             }
           },

          {
              text: "Cancel"
             , 'class': "btn-warning"
             , click: function () {
                 editBanTicketDiag.dialog('destroy');
             }

          }
        ]

    });
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a question about Jquery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out. You must go to  jquery.dialog.js file

and on line number 117 on show function replace it's code with:

```
var show = function () {
//call the bootstrap modal to handle the show events (fade effects, body class and backdrop div)
            //$msgbox.modal('show');
            $msgbox.modal({
                show: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: true
            });
        };
```